# The Following Classes Could not Be Found Error (latest version)

Tags: java, android, gradle

Im getting the error

```
The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.design.widget.NavigationView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
Tip: Try to build the project.
```

Heres my module app:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

I've tried to rebuild, clean and change the implementations but nothings seems to work

Does anyone know how I could fix this?? it started when I updated android studio and created a new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependency is mixed of support library and AndroidX which is not right. **Refactor** it to AndroidX using **Android Studio**.

**Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** and press **Do Refactor**

You have to use

```
androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
```

instead of

```
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
```

Comment: How about when using custom view?